# Can I enhance truss storage capacity above my garage with a beam?

Tags: storage, truss

We are getting ready to move into a new house that has storage above the garage ceiling. I was told it could hold 40 lbs per square ft. The trusses are spanning about 20 ft.

Can I put an exposed beam mid garage to double that?

My wife has a ton of heavy fiesta ware which I’m guessing is just going to be too heavy to put up there the way it is now.

Comment: Can the weight be spread around a wide area?  A beam will increase load carrying, but if the weight needs to be in a small area, would think about supporting that area more than just a beam half a floor away.

Comment: Just wondering... who told you it could hold 40#/s/f? (When you say trusses, I get concerned, because trusses generally aren't supposed to hold much of anything.)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate -  Agreed, converting (barring errors), it comes to 195Kg/sqm.  That's already on the high side for loads on top of the truss.  I don't think it's the correct figure for loading the bottom member of the truss.

Comment: All depends on the truss design. "Storage trusses" (aka "Attic room trusses") are a thing. They are built differently than roof trusses not intended for storage and/or occupied space inside the truss. A 40 PSF load would be entirely normal for those. The effect of adding a beam would be very much "ask your engineer" territory, as that can be non-intuitive with trusses.

Answer (score 2):

You could add the beam in the center, however if the roof structure is done with trusses, they are designed differently so that a center support does not necessarily give a greater weight rating across the entire bottom cord.

That said, a Fiesta ware 12 piece dinner set, (place setting for 4) weighs less than 20 lbs on average.  So if you had placed a sheet of plywood 2x4 ft" it could support 320Lbs.  Thats place settings for 64 people!  If your wife has more dishes than that, spread them around in more boxes and you will be fine.

Comment: There's legitimate concern that the load rating is for the _top_ of the truss and not the bottom chord. I'd be careful giving advice in that direction.

Comment: Info from truss building companies is such that the design of the  bottom chord when planned to be used for storage gives a per/ft rating of 40 lbs.  The OP stated that there is storage above the garage, as is normal for many homes.  Built as designed that storage would be allowing 40lbs/sq'.  The top truss load is different depending on the type of roofing material planned.  This is normal and common in truss design.

Comment: I'll take your word for it, but 40 seems like a massive load. I'd have a hard time trusting those little gussets with thousands of lbs. each.

Comment: Here in fla most all the homes are built with trusses. They can be massively strong when designed correctly.  "the strength of the triangle"   Hurricane Ian had a number of big trees come down on the condo roofs. (over the second floor).   Roof repairs were needed to the tiles, and decks, not one truss was compromised.

Comment: Here too. I suspect everywhere anymore. However, you're talking about roof loads. We're looking into _ceiling_ loads.

Comment: still the wood used is southern yellow pine. Very dense. As said when required to have the bottom chord carry the load of storage, they are designed that way and have the strength needed .  Those gussets are strong mothers.  I tried to pull one out of a scrap truss...gave up...darn near impossible.